# how to get all the images from a folder with extension .jpg using xslt

Tags: xslt

For example,I have this folder by name, test under which some n number of images are stored with .jpg extension as well as some log files. Now I need top get only .jpg images but not log files using XSLT. Is this possible.?

Answer (score 0):

In Saxon 9.7 with XSLT 3.0 support you can get a sequence of URIs with a certain file name ending with e.g. `uri-collection('directory-name?select=*.jpg')`. I am not sure what you want to do exactly when you say "get all the images", the suggestion would allow you to get the file URIs of the images, e.g. `file:/root/directory-name/file1.jpg`.

Comment: Hi Martin, as you said i can get the particular image by file:/root/directory-name/file1.jpg but i have lot of images file1.jpg,file2.jpg,...filen.jpg. In this scenario, how will i get all the images till filen.jpg excluding .log files in that folder.

Comment: As posted, `uri-collection('directory-name?select=*.jpg')` returns a sequence of collection URIs of files with the ending `.jpg` in the folder `directory-name`. Requires Saxon 9.7 and XSLT 3.0.